# need GSON to return a Java JSONArray

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm not able to return a JSONArray, instead my object appears to be a String.  the value of *myArray* is the same value as *jsonString*.  The object is a String object and not a **JSONArray**.  and both *jsonString* and *myArray* prnt:

```
[{"id":"100002930603211",
  "name":"Aardvark Jingleheimer",
  "picture":"shortenedExample.jpg" },
 {"id":"537815695",
   "name":"Aarn Mc",
   "picture":"shortendExample.jpg" },
 {"id":"658471072",
   "name":"Adrna opescu",
   "picture":"shortenedExample.jpg"
}]
```

How can I convert this to an actual Java **JSONArray**?  thanks!

```
           //arrPersons is an ArrayList

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String jsonString = gson.toJson(arrPersons);

        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        JsonElement myElement = parser.parse(jsonString);
        JsonArray myArray = myElement.getAsJsonArray();
```

Comment: This can't be right.  getAsJsonArray() returns a JSONArray. Java is statically typed, what you wrote above would not compile if myArray wasn't really a JsonArray.

Comment: that's part of my question.  the Gson JsonArray object is different than Java JSONArray object.  I would like to create a JSONArray.

Comment: ? There is no *the* Java JSONArray object.  Do you mean JSONArray from http://json.org?

Comment: And if you are using Gson, why bother with json.org stuff?

Comment: Hi Max,  this is my first Java project so please forgive my ignorance on missing that JSONArray was not a Java Object.  I did figure out how to accomplish my task of taking a JSONArray and alphabetizing by "name" element.  I posted the code below.  The path was  JSONArray -- ArrayList--sort list--back to JSONArray through GSON.  Would love to hear of a better way though.  thanks!

Comment: Try out some of the suggestions I outlined in the answer below! All the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do what you want without writing out a json string and then re-reading it:

```
List<Person> arrPersons = new ArrayList<Person>();

// populate your list

Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonElement element = gson.toJsonTree(arrPersons, new TypeToken<List<Person>>() {}.getType());

if (! element.isJsonArray()) {
// fail appropriately
    throw new SomeException();
}

JsonArray jsonArray = element.getAsJsonArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public JSONArray getMessage(String response){

    ArrayList<Person> arrPersons = new ArrayList<Person>();
    try {
        // obtain the response
        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
        // get the array
        JSONArray persons=jsonResponse.optJSONArray("data");


        // iterate over the array and retrieve single person instances
        for(int i=0;i<persons.length();i++){
            // get person object
            JSONObject person=persons.getJSONObject(i);
            // get picture url
            String picture=person.optString("picture");
            // get id
            String id=person.optString("id");
            // get name
            String name=person.optString("name");

            // construct the object and add it to the arraylist
            Person p=new Person();
            p.picture=picture;
            p.id=id;
            p.name=name;
            arrPersons.add(p);
        }
        //sort Arraylist
        Collections.sort(arrPersons, new PersonSortByName());


    Gson gson = new Gson();
    //gson.toJson(arrPersons);

    String jsonString = gson.toJson(arrPersons);

    sortedjsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);



    } catch (JSONException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return sortedjsonArray;

}



public class PersonSortByName implements Comparator<Person>{

    public int compare(Person o1, Person o2) {
    return o1.name.compareTo(o2.name);
    }
    }

  public class Person{
       public String picture;
       public String id;
       public String name;
  }
```